# Upload a file by filling it in HTTPRequest!

Tags: http, httpwebrequest

I am wondering, if I create a new HttpRequest, and put the content of a simple file inside this request, would I be able to read the content on the server side by aspx page? in other words would that be equivalent to upload control?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot access/upload local files via XmlHttpRequest.